# Do you think responsive design is good for an enterprise website?

Tags: responsive-design, responsive, enterprise

I have a few survey questions for developers that work on their company's website and are familiar with Responsive Web Design.  I'm targeting developers whose role is more on the front end of the website and is consumer facing.  Preferably working at an enterprise company.

If you fit this description, please answer the questions below.  Greatly appreciated!

1. If you're comfortable sharing - what is your company, position, company size and industry?
2. Do you think responsive design is good for an enterprise website?
3. Would you consider responsive design for your company’s site?
4. Do you feel your company's site is old and in need of a rebuild?
   a) If yes, would you consider using tools to make your current site responsive without having to rebuild from scratch? b) If yes, what kind of tools would be helpful to make your site responsive?
5. Is it important to you that site (re)development is done in-house?
     a)    If yes – Do you feel your team has the skills to do this?
   b)   If yes – Do you feel your team has the time to do this? c)    If yes – Would you consider tools to help make the process easier, faster?  d)   If no – why not? e)    If no – Have you looked into platforms and services to help you with this process?
6. How much of a say do you and your development team have in the decision making process (of a site redevelopment)?
7. How often does the Marketing team consult with your team on marketing technology or website technology decisions?
8. What sites do you use to research programming tools?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a market research poll. This is a Q&A site about UX. I'd suggest putting this up on survey monkey or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Your analytics and traffic sources should dictate this decision.

First and foremost let's work with what you [should] know, which is current technology usage by site visitors. I suspect that it's less than 10% mobile. This might be an early indication that yours might not fit the use case for justifying extra resources and new, modern ways of approaching all the content you produce for the site.

The second part of the decision is a bit less scientific and has to do with anticipating whether the number we looked at above might change for any reason.
- Is Twitter becoming an important channel for leads? Most Twitter engagement occurs on a mobile device, so marketing resources could be justifiably deployed to provide an experience, even if somewhat limited, which serves that particular funnel.
- Is there a use case for your service or lead generation that is fundamentally un-desktop? Perhaps yours is a service which people think of or reach out to in some on-the-go setting where their only means of access is their mobile phone. This would indicate that your observed mobile traffic might be low due to limited utility, in which case the mobile traffic and engagement should be expected to more than double almost immediately following a proper responsive rollout.
- Does a visitor's particular goal make them any more or less likely to proceed through your funnel on desktop vs mobile? For example, an onboarding flow which requires the upload of documents from your computer cannot be completed on any device other than the user's computer.

I would advocate trying to answer this question mathematically with input from your marketing and sales teams, and understand how mobile may or may not fit with their goals and strategies. Maybe the sales folks will say "you know, I always direct people to our website when we're out at lunch and it's a complete dead-end." This certainly changes the way we think about our 10% traffic number from earlier, right? That 10% might represent 50% of company revenue.

So, empirically assess the current state of mobile engagement, identify the impact a mobile-friendly offering would have on planned sales and marketing efforts, and quantify the potential impact of a responsive undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

The RWD solution is attractive. A company mainly needs to build and manage one RWD website. The recent survey in an influential article explaining why 2013 is the year of RWD. Many other website managers and analysts accepts this belief and shared case studies of how RWD websites have brought joy to device-hopping users & Customers.

RWD’s major advantage is, it’s painless to keep the site’s content updated across different versions of the site. Site managers can update information and designs in just one location, and all versions of that site are automatically updated. Further, content management system (CMS) is opt.

Nothing’s perfect, however, so let’s discuss a few reasons why RWD might not be a good solution for web design.

RWD delivers the exact same content and experience to all device users.however, a device changes the needs of a user. research shows that mobile phone owners are heavily focused on deals when shopping. The content they see needs to be more focused on promotions, and RWD can’t do this easily.

> RWD also receives poor grades for page load times & No Compatibility For IE 8.

This is due to content such as images, tables and other formatting that’s too large and cumbersome for mobile devices. If a site is conversion-focused (such as an ecommerce site), slower page-load times can dramatically reduce performance.

When evaluating RWD, consider these questions:

- Do I have plans to change my website?
- Do I publish a lot of content that’s updated very frequently?
- Is my site more focused on delivering information versus complex functionality?

A “YES” response for all three suggests that RWD might be worth consideration.

Even corporate belive that, simple RWD site can make great user experience for its customers. So, I conclude that, by reducing the drawbacks of RWD while still keeping many of the benefits.